# "Flitter lip!" to mean 'darn'

Tags: word-usage, phrases, slang, euphemisms

My dad used to say "flitter lip" a lot. Like, 'oh darn', or maybe a way to cuss in front of us kids. I can't find any reference to its use beyond him. **Has anyone else heard this, or is this maybe a variation on a more common euphemism?**

Possible clues:

- My dad served in WWII in Germany and France. Maybe it was a twist on a German exclamation?
- He was from Oklahoma, raised in New Mexico, worked some migrant work in Cal in the 30's.
- They had a family jazz band. Maybe it's a trumpet player's reference? Like he's playing and gets a "blattt", and blames it on a flitter lip?

Comment: Sounds like a variation of "fiddle faddle".

Comment: I can't find any on-line reference to "flitter lip" like that. This is probably something your dad (or someone he knew) made up and it just never caught on anywhere else.

Comment: The only newspaper mention "of "flitter-lip" that I've been able to find is regrettably thin on context. It comes from a set of [very brief trial court notes](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/2012218613/1888-08-08/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22flitter-lip%22) in the [Winnsboro South Carolina] _Fairfield News and Herald_ of August 8, 1888: "TRIAL JUSTICE COURT.—Before Trial Justice Cathcart on Friday the case of Louisa Pagan, assault and battery on Jim Hamilton, better known as 'Flitter-lip Jim' was heard. Verdict not guilty." We are not told how Hamilton acquired that sobriquet.

Comment: I don't know if this works in American English but in British English the word "Flip" is often used like that. I believe that it is derived from "Flipping" or "Flipping heck" which is a euphemism for an obscene and semi-blasphemous two word expression which you can possibly guess. "Flitter lip" I have never heard but is sounds like a euphemism for the same expression to me. After all "darn" is a euphemism for "damn".

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned a few years ago (in a comment beneath the posted question) that there is one relatively old instance of *flitter-lip* in a [brief news item](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/2012218613/1888-08-08/ed-1/seq-3/#date1=1756&index=0&rows=20&words=Flitter+Flitter-lip+lip&searchType=basic&sequence=0&state=&date2=1963&proxtext=%22flitter-lip%22&y=14&x=7&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) in the *[Winnsboro, South Carolina] Fairfield News and Herald* (August 8, 1888):

> TRIAL JUSTICE COURT.—Before Trial Justice Cathcart on Friday the case of Louisa Pagan, assault and battery on Jim Hamilton, better known as '**Flitter-lip** Jim' was heard. Verdict not guilty.

Although there is no explanation in the item of how Hamilton acquired his nickname, *Dictionary of American Regional English*, volume II, D–H (1991) notes that *flitter* sometimes appears as a variant form of *flutter*, suggesting that *flitter-lip* might carry a meaning along the lines of "loose-lips" or "flapjaw"—approximately, "someone who talks to much."

More to the point of the posted question, however, is another DARE entry for *flitter*:

> **flitter** *intj* Used as a mild expression of annoyance [Cited instances **1954** *Harder Coll.* **c[entral] w[estern] TN,** Aw flitter. **1968** DARE (Qu. NN8a, Exclamations of annoyance or disgust: *"Oh ___________, I've lost my glasses again."*) Inf[ormant] LA28, Flitter.

The two cited instances of this interjection are from central western Tennessee and from Louisiana—two noncontiguous (but not terribly distant) states in the western part of the Old South. Oklahoma (where the poster's father lived at one time) is farther west but again not very distant from either Tennessee or Louisiana.  One possibility, then, is that "flitter lip!" used as an interjection is simply an extended form of "flitter!" used in the same way.

Another possibility is that *flitter-lip* may be a variant of *flutter-lip*, which may convey any of several specific slang meanings, although I have not found these recorded in slang dictionaries. One use of the term, from Willie Nelson, [*The Facts of Life: and Other Dirty Jokes*](https://books.google.com/books?id=c_hE-G_OLWEC&pg=PA84&dq=%22flutter-lips%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJlcWsnbaEAxUfATQIHSyqD8o4ChDoAXoECAsQAg#v=onepage&q=%22flutter-lips%22&f=false) (2002) implies stammering or stuttering:

> I came to town [Nashville, Tennessee] with "Night Life," "Mr. Record Man," "Crazy," "Funny How Time Slips Away," and a few others. Hank [Cochran] had heard some of my songs one night at Tootsie's Orchid Lounge in Nashville. Everyone hung out at Tootsie's. She loved all the crazy people, Fluffo and **Flutter Lips** (better known as Wayne Walker and Mel Tillis), Faron Young, Hank, Charlie Dick (Patsy Cline's husband), Little Jimmy Dickens, and Billy Walker.

Nelson doesn't explain the nickname "Flutter Lips," but Mel Tillis was famous for having a serious stutter except when he sang (which he did very well).

Possibly to the same effect is this instance from Ramon Adams, [*The Old-Time Cowhand*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NAFA_x2KgQUC&pg=PA20&dq=%22flutter-lip%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwixxpm_o7aEAxWOLzQIHWWxBt0Q6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=%22flutter-lip%22&f=false) (1948/1961):

> When the [auguring] match came off, our champion, havin' some talent for poetry, started off with such giggle talk as, "The hoss he neigh, can you tell what he say? The cow she moo, the bull does too' the dog he bark, till the moon goes dark; the lion he roar, till his throat gets sore; the catamount squall like a bronc in the stall; the rabbit he run, 'cause he's a-skeered of a gun; the kyote yip, like he's got the **flutter-lip**." He goes on like this till he runs plumb through the animal kingdom.

The "old-time cowhand" narrating this story is, I believe, from Texas. In context, the narrator seems to be equating the coyote's "yip-yip-yip-yip-yip-yip" call with a stutter.

Another uses the term to describe certain vocalizations or musical sounds that are not actual words. From Heidi Von Gunden, *The Music of Pauline Oliveros* (1983) [combined snippets]:

> The third electroniclike motive is a series of percussive envelopes titled "lip pops," "tongue clicks," "snap fingers" and "**flutter lips**." Although these sounds resemble childlike sonic play, they are used in a serious context and are difficult to perform because they demand strict ensemble precision.
>
> ...
>
> The second phrase introduces muting while mixing ring modulation with white noise (as in "shung" sung by the tenors in measure 6), and the third phrase features percussive sound and new attacks. "Wht" becomes a version of white noise; "bbbbbbbbt" (**flutter lips**) is a new percussive sound, and " pow-wowōwowōwowō" is another ring modulation. The separate dynamic markings for each sound and frequent tempo fluctuations clearly define the phrase structure so that the listener recognizes an initiation and conclusion of musical ideas.

Similarly, Cleo Coyle, [*Bulletproof Barista*](https://books.google.com/books?id=RJCsEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA232&dq=%22flutter-lipped%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjc3I-MnLaEAxX2ETQIHVUDD2AQ6AF6BAgMEAI#v=onepage&q=%22flutter-lipped%22&f=false) (2023) uses "flutter-lipped" to describe to the "pththththt" sound also known as a Bronx cheer:

> "I'm high on life," Jerry cracked, adding a **flutter-lipped** Bronx cheer. So give us a kiss then."

I don't know which of these possibilities (random expansion of *flitter* used as an interjection, variant of *flutter-lip* in the sense of "stammerer," or variant of *flutter-lip* in the sense of "Bronx cheer-like sound") is the most likely source of *flitter-lip* as used by the poster's father, but I suspect that one or more of these sources may have influenced his usage.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard the phrase before. If your father didn't invent it himself, it likely has a very limited scope.

My guess is that your father or someone invented the word to use as an alternative to swearing in front of children or others who might be offended.